# Warning: Unable to register kotlin.Lazy for reflection using Quarkus

Tags: kotlin, cdi, quarkus, jandex

I have the following `data class` in my Kotlin code that uses Quarkus as a server side framework.

```
data class Location(
    val id: String,
    val serviceTimeInMinutes: Long,
    val openingTimes: List<OpeningTime>,
) {
    val sortedOpeningTimes: List<OpeningTime> by lazy {
        openingTimes.sortedWith { o1, o2 ->
            if (o1.weekday == o2.weekday) {
                o1.from.compareTo(o2.from)
            } else {
                o1.weekday.compareTo(o2.weekday)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I now run `./gradlew quarkusDev`, I get the following warning:

```
2023-08-22 15:13:28,401 WARN  [io.qua.dep.ste.ReflectiveHierarchyStep] (build-4) Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
    - kotlin.Lazy (source: <unknown>)
    - kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 (source: <unknown>)
Consider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.
```

When I change the property to an ordinary property by removing the `by lazy`-block, the line with the `kotlin.Lazy` disappears as expected.

However, if I wanted to lazily execute that block, is there a way to get rid of that warning? And is there a way to get rid of the warning for `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1`?

##### Note

I am aware of the configuration properties `quarkus.index-dependency.<...>`, which I already used to get rid of that warning for the threeten library like this:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.threeten.group-id=org.threeten
quarkus.index-dependency.threeten.artifact-id=threeten-extra
```

I suppose if I knew `group-id` and `artifact-id` of Kotlin (if they exist), adding extra lines in the `application.properties` might be worth a try.

Comment: Are you already using the [quarkus kotlin extension](https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkus/quarkus-kotlin)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the extension. Quarkus platform and plugin versions are both `3.1.3.Final`. Further, I'm using the `kotlin.jvm` and `kotlin.plugin.allopen` plugins.

Comment: Another piece of information here: I'm using gradle as build tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the solution myself: `Lazy` and `Function1` both are implemented in the kotlin stdlib.

Adding the stdlib to the Quarkus index dependencies with

```
quarkus.index-dependency.kotlin.group-id=org.jetbrains.kotlin
quarkus.index-dependency.kotlin.artifact-id=kotlin-stdlib
```

is sufficient to remove the warning.

Probably it would be a nice feature for the Quarkus Kotlin extension to allow devs omitting that additional configuration -  <s>so I think I'll raise an issue there</s> I've raised [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35504).